# Using asp how to create formatted currency with commas?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Using asp.  Trying to format a decimal number to add commas.  Are there simple to use functions or techniques in asp to go from a decimal value to currency format with commas?

Examples:

```
DecimalValue = 3439.01     CurrencyValue = "    3,439.01"
DecimalValue = 3843838.38  CurrencyValue = "3,843,838.00"
```

Answer (score 3):

use the vbscript function FormatCurrency

complete syntax is:
FormatCurrency(Expression[,NumDigAfterDec[,
IncLeadingDig[,UseParForNegNum[,GroupDig]]]])

example:

```
FormatCurrency(20000)
```

output = $20,000.00

example of setting number of decimals:

```
FormatCurrency(20000,5)
```

output = $20,000.00000

Comment: VbScript won't work for my scenario.  Do you happen to know of an asp code that might add commas?  thx

Comment: @Marc Noon: Your question is tagged with VBScript though? Also, are you talking about Classic ASP or ASP.NET?

Comment: @Marc: Classic ASP is a blend of html and VBScript. With html you can use JavaScript, but there are no "asp codes" other than vbscript or javascript. If you do mean ASP.Net, it is a totally different implementation, and should never just be referenced as ASP due to the confusion with the classic version. Can you please clarify which you are using?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Carlton Jenke's answer, there are 2 functions you can use for this (you mentioned formatting as a currency in the question title but don't include currency symbols in the body of the question):

1. `formatnumber` returns an expression formatted as a number.
2. `formatcurrency` returns an expression formatted as a currency value
   using the currency symbol defined in the system control panel.

Both functions take the same arguments, those being:

```
Expression [,NumDigitsAfterDecimal [,IncludeLeadingDigit
[,UseParensForNegativeNumbers [,GroupDigits]]]]
```

1. `Expression` is the only required argument, that being the number
   you wish to format.
2. `NumDigitsAfterDecimal` is a numeric value specifying how many
   decimal places you want to round to. The default value is -1, which
   indicates that the computer's regional settings should be used.
3. `IncludeLeadingDigit` is a tristate constant (see below) which
   specifies whether or not you want to include a leading zero for
   values between -1 and 1.
4. `UseParensForNegativeNumbers` is another tristate constant which
   specifies whether or not you want negative values to be enclosed in
   parentheses, rather than using a minus symbol.
5. `GroupDigits`, which is the argument you're after, is also a
   tristate constant and is used to specify whether or not you want to
   group numbers using the system's group delimiter.

The tristate constants takes one of the following for the value:

1. `-2` is the default and indicates that the default value from the computer's regional setting should be used.
2. `-1` is true.
3. `0` is false.

Comment: You're welcome. Honestly, I didn't expect any feedback from you on this given how old it is; I just happened across it in my travels and wanted to provide a bit more detail for anyone who may do the same in the suture.