# VB ASP Convert String/Float to Currency/Money Format

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Well Folks,

I'm having a hard time trying to convert a simple String to Currency Format to a asp classic page...

I already tried the Culture stuff, but I think all of that is 3.5 Framework.

```
<% Dim culturePT As New CultureInfo("pt-PT") %> '' This freaking work in 3.5 but in 2.0 NO
<%= value.ToString("C", culturePT ) %> '' Expected 1.234,00



<%= "1234".ToString("C") %> '' Expected 1.234,00
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your time!

Reference page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Classic ASP uses VBScript scripting engine by default which doesn't support strongly typed variables *(VBScript is type-less)*. I'd imagine you are probably just getting errors trying to run this code as it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: yupi. nothing more! But has to have some solution for this... I think =/

Comment: FormatCurrency doesnt work as well... probably by my flopness

Comment: Solution for what? Your posting .Net code *(I assume)* but say you want Classic ASP, which is it?

Comment: Your tags aren't as mutually exclusive as, say, [asp-classic] plus [c#] would be, but they're still contradictory: the scripting language for classic ASP is VBScript, not VB.

Comment: Duplicate of [Using asp how to create formatted currency with commas?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5783731/692942). This question has been asked umpteen times before doesn't need yet another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript and VB are very similar, but they're **not** identical. There's no `dim ... as` in VBScript, for example. And AFAIK, there's no `value.ToString...` type of syntax in any flavor of VB; unlike all those language with curly braces, the period is not some sort of magic wand operator.

The way to use the FormatCurrency function in VBScript is the same way you'd use any other function in VBScript:

```
dim x, y
x = 1234
y = FormatCurrency(x)
```

That will format the number according the server's regional settings. You can twiddle with a few options, but they all still depend on the server's regional settings, and there's no programmatic way to override those for just your page. For example, you can force two digits after the decimal point, no leading zeros, parentheses for negative numbers, and grouping of digits, but the actual characters used for the decimal point and the group separator will depend on the server's settings.

```
y = FormatCurrency(x,2,0,-1,-1)
```

If you need more control than that, you'll need to write your own currency formatting function.

Comment: @Lankymart: how is this even remotely "doing it for them"? I do agree with the duplicate you found, though; dunno why it didn't turn up in my searches.

Comment: thanks, already got it work! I know that VB has limitation, I didn't know about the typeless crape but anyway I was under-pression to get it work and already tried any of that stuff :)
What was happening was really fun! In the start of the code value object was being filled with value = "123 €", so the € symbol was messing with the formatation.